# Array comprehension synthax with vue.js, quasar and ES6

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, quasar-framework

I want to use array comprehension in my quasar project.
Quasar version : 0.17.*
Vue.js version : 2.9.6, which uses es6 (aka ES2015)

When I use :

```
let newList = oldList.map(function (item) { return item.value })
```

everything works as expected. But when I use :

```
let newList = [for (item of oldList) item.value]
```

I get the following `synthax error`:

```
Failed to compile.

[...]

  13:26  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  11 | export function setList (state, oldList) {
  12 |   
> 13 |   let newList = [for (item of oldList) item.value]
     |                  ^
  14 |
```

why ? Isn't this synthax supposed to be correct too ?

Comment: `for .. of` is a statement, you can't use it as an expression

Comment: this would explain that , thank you.

Comment: afaik Array comprehensions have been discussed but ES has decided against them and no browser does support them anymore. If you just want some cleaner looking code, I'd suggest an arrow function: `let newList = oldList.map(item => item.value)`

Comment: awesome. Post this as an answer ? ;)